# Sync the CreateView of Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-studio, async-await

I am working on an Android app which is mix of java and Native code. I am facing a issue related to synch of different thread data. 
Here is a scenerio.

In my main activity I have a listview. On selecting an item in the listview, I have to create 3 fragments and I have create a model on the native side as well which will provide data to represents various Fragments. The result of work on the native side will give me some details about the TextView value and Buttons states in the three fragments.
So in the onclick handler of the listview, I created a thread t2 which launchs the on the native side  using JNI call and on the UI thread t1, I started created my fragments. When the t2 is done it will broadcast a local intent so that the activity knows that the native code is ready. In the handling of this intent I have to update the UIs of fragments like button states and textviews. But I am facing a race condition here that sometimes CreateView of the fragments is complete and sometimes not. So I am not able to update my Fragments in the handling of intent properly.

So I need a mechanism where in the handling of intent I wait for the CreateView for all the fragments to complete and then I can update UI of the fragments. In future I can have 1-2 more fragments.

So what is the best scalable mechanism where I can wait for multiple Fragment's CreateView complete action and than can update them . Note here that each of the Fragments are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you basically need a way for your Activity to know if all fragments are done with createview and then handle the intent.

One relatively simple way is make a simple interface FragmentCallBack which can be used by MainActivity to keep track of all fragments which have been created

```
public Interface FragmentCallBack {
    public void onFragmentCreated(Fragment f)
}
```

Let your activity implement this interface where in it can keep track of which fragment is created. Also in Activity have a variable to store the received intent and a boolean to keep track whether intent is received

```
private Intent recievedIntent
private boolean isIntentRecieved
List<Fragment> createdFragments
```

Now implement the functions to handle fragment completion and receipt of intent

```
@Override 
public void onFragmentCreated(Fragment f) {
  createdFragments.add(f)
  if (isIntentRecieved) {
     //handle the intent for this fragment
  }
}

@Override
public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent) {
  isIntentRecieved = true
  recievedIntent = intent
  for (Fragment f: createdFragments) {
     //handle the intent
  }
}
```

Now the change needed for your fragments will be to inform the activity of createView completion

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //do createview stuff
 ((FragmentCallback) (getActivity())).onFragmentCreated(this);
 }
```

So now, your intent related tasks will be done to your fragments only after completion

Another, way to do it would be to let each fragment handle the intent individually, however, in your thread delay the broadcast of intent until all fragments are created. To do this you can let your activity pass the number of fragments it wants to create to the service (which does the native call etc) while creating it. Now whenever activity gets a fragment complete (as in previous example),  it informs the service of it and service increases the counter. Service delays broadcasting of intent until the count is reached. Off course, the counter needs to be synchronized to avoid race condition